# CakePHP 3 Skip Migration in Production

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.4, phinx

I have a Migration that failed in production after executing several commands that I can not execute again, is there a way to skip a migration?

Comment: If you can access the database, add the migration to the phinxlog table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a mark_migrated command you can use to set particular migrations as migrated and this will mark them as not needing to be run. [CakePHP Documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/migrations.html#mark-migrated-marking-a-migration-as-migrated)

You can use the following where target is the timestamp of the migration you do not want to mark as not needing to be run.

```
bin/cake migrations mark_migrated --target=20151016204000
```

Comment: Note that this command will run _all_ migrations up to target (including target). If you want to cherry-pick one migration to mark as migrated, simply add `--only` as an additional parameter to @KaffineAddict's code example (this is also in the docs that are linked to).